Creating a virtual QgsVectorLayer with PyQGIS outside of QGIS
In QGIS' built in python prompt, I can do this
>>> linesfile
'C:\\Users\\path\\to\\Lines.csv'
>>> mylayer = QgsVectorLayer(linesfile, "GPSLines", "ogr")
>>> mylayer.isValid()
True
>>> mylayer.featureCount()
6624

And successfully create a virtual layer that references the freshly created one:
>>> vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("?query=SELECT * FROM 'GPSLines'", 'myvlayer', 'virtual')
>>> vlayer.isValid()
True
>>> vlayer.featureCount()
6624

However, trying the same from an external editor (VSCode), it doesn't behave as expected. The created layer seems to be invalid, but I can't see why or even find an error message that explains more. It feels as if the 'GPSLines' layer that I just created disappears into thin air.
mylayer = QgsVectorLayer(linesfile, "GPSLines", "ogr")
mylayername = mylayer.name()
if not mylayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load")
else:
    print("Layer loaded.")
    print("Original number of features: " + str(mylayer.featureCount()))
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("?query=SELECT * FROM 'GPSLines'", 'myvlayer','virtual')
if not vlayer.isValid():
    error_msg = vlayer.lastError()
    print(f"Virtual layer creation failed with error: {error_msg}")
    print("Filtered Layer failed to load")
else:
    print("Filtered Layer loaded.")
    print("Filtered number of features: " + str(vlayer.featureCount()))

Output:
Layer loaded.
Original number of features: 6624
Virtual layer creation failed with error:
Filtered Layer failed to load

Any help or pointers welcome - I have no clue where to look further.
